# PHP array with value returns NULL

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have an array which is converted from CSV file. I have there two keys ID and NAME.

If I show key NAME everything is OK. But when i tried to get key ID, i always get NULL but key ID have value set.

[image]

```
function convertCsvToArray($filename='', $delimiter=';')
{
  if(!file_exists($filename))
    return FALSE;

  $header = NULL;
  $data = array();
  if (($handle = fopen($filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
  {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE)
    {
      if(!$header)
        $header = $row;
      else
        $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
    }
    fclose($handle);
  }
  return $data;
}

$array = convertCsvToArray('/path/to/csv/categories.csv',';');

/*
$array structure is
  array(2){
    ["ID"] => 3
    ["NAME"] => Some name
  }
*/
foreach($array as $category){
  var_dump($category["ID"]); //return NULL
  var_dump($category["NAME"]); //return "Some name"
}
```

CSV dump

```
ID;NAME
3;Značkové nealko nápoje
4;Nízkoenergetické nápoje
5;Minerálne vody, sóda
6;Tetrapack 0.2l a 0.5l
```

print_r for $array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [NAME] => Značkové nealko nápoje
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 4
            [NAME] => Nízkoenergetické nápoje
        )
)
```

print_r for $category

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 3
    [NAME] => Značkové nealko nápoje
)
```

Comment: How about including the actual code, rather than teeny pictures of it?

Comment: Also... `var_dump($category)` . . . The *whole darned thing,* as PHP sees it.  Or, heck, `var_dump($array)`.

Comment: Can you show the content of your CSV file please ?

Comment: My guess is there's a space in the ID heading.

Comment: No, i have same content, what is here. I converted CSV to UTF-8 in Notepad, cause it's exported from excel and i need good encoding of special chars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here comes from [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Invisible characters are added at the begining of the file, so they are prefixed to the "ID" key, so PHP can't find the ID key, and shows NULL values.

Convert your CSV file to UTF-8 without BOM and it will fix your problem.

Comment: You are right, thank you! You saved my deathline. :)